# Update all but one of duplicate records in table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server table that has duplicate entries in one of the columns (`object_id`) e.g.:

```
+----+-----------+------------+
| id | object_id | status_val |
+----+-----------+------------+
|  1 |         1 |          0 | 
|  2 |         1 |          0 | 
|  3 |         1 |          0 | 
|  4 |         2 |          0 | 
|  5 |         3 |          0 | 
|  6 |         3 |          0 | 
+----+-----------+------------+
```

I need to update all of their statuses except for one when there is duplication in the `object_id` column. So in the table above `object_id` 1 and 3 are duplicated. So I would want to change their `status_val` to 2, except one of the entries. The result would look like:

```
| id | object_id | status_val |
+----+-----------+------------+
|  1 |         1 |          0 | 
|  2 |         1 |          2 | 
|  3 |         1 |          2 | 
|  4 |         2 |          0 | 
|  5 |         3 |          0 | 
|  6 |         3 |          2 | 
+----+-----------+------------+
```

It doesn't matter which one of the duplicated rows has it's status updated.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See my answer, its very small and simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may solve this problem without a join, which means it should have better performance. The idea is to group the data by your object_id, counting the row number of each object_id. This is what "partition by" does. Then you can update where the row_num is > 1. This will update all duplicated object_id except the first one!

```
update t set t.status_val = 'some_status' 
from (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by object_id order by (select null)) row_num  
    from foo
) t 
where row_num > 1
```

On a test table of 82944 records, the performance was such (your mileage may vary!): 
Table 'test'. Scan count 5, logical reads 82283, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
CPU time = 141 ms,  elapsed time = 150 ms.

We can certainly also solve this problem by using an inner join, however, in general this should lead to more logical reads and higher CPU:

Table 'test'. Scan count 10, logical reads 83622, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Workfile'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 4, logical reads 167426, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
CPU time = 342 ms,  elapsed time = 233 ms.

To loop over the results and update in smaller batches:

```
declare @rowcount int = 1;
declare @batch_size int = 1000;

while @rowcount > 0 
begin
    update top(@batch_size) t set t.status_val = 'already updated'
    from (
        select *, row_number() over(partition by object_id order by (select null)) row_num  
        from foo
        where status_val <> 'already updated' 
    ) t 
    where row_num > 1 
    set @rowcount = @@rowcount;
end
```

This will help keep locking down if other concurrent sessions are trying to access this table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tested this over the weekend and it works well! Thanks again.

Comment: Hi. I actually tried testing this against a larger dataset and found it was taking too long. There are > 2 million entries in the table, and the query has been running for over 3 hours. Is there a way I could batch the updates so it doesn't run on the entire table at the same time?
Perhaps I could run it from a separate stand alone windows service?

Comment: This could be bc of the commit size. You could do this in a loop as long as the "status_val" can filter out rows you have already updated. I'll update my answer with the looping option.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Table
SET Table.status_val = '2'
FROM Table
INNER JOIN
(SELECT id, row_number()OVER(PARTITION BY object_id ORDER BY id) as seq FROM Table) other_table
ON Table.id = other_table.id AND seq <> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your question, it seems that for each value of object_id, you want to keep the status_val = 0 for the object_id with lowest id and = 2 for the others. If that is indeed the case, and IF an object_id repeats only a maximum of 3 times, then I have a very simple solution for you. Use the modulo or remainder operator to get what you want. Here is the answer which I will explain later:

```
update [MyTable]
set status_val = 2
where (id%3) != 1
```

When you divide any value of `id` by 3, the remainder can be only 0,1 or 2. So, for each object_id where id%3 is not 1, we change the status_val to 2.

Before executing the above code, see the output of this query -

```
select id, (id%3) as flg, object_id, status_val 
from MyTable
```