# Update only first record from duplicate entries in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help trying to update a table that has multiple duplicate records, but I am stuck.

I have this table, and I need to update `im_cust9` with the `alt_item_id1` value.

The query I am using to get this result from the table is the following:

```
 SELECT  
     o.item_id, o.alt_item_id1, o.im_cust9, o.owner_id, o.if_updatestamp
 FROM 
     item_master o
 INNER JOIN
     (SELECT 
          alt_item_id1, COUNT(*) AS dupeCount
      FROM 
          item_master 
      WHERE 
          owner_id = 'GIII' AND alt_item_id1 <> ''
      GROUP BY 
          alt_item_id1  
      HAVING 
          COUNT(*) > 1) oc ON o.alt_item_id1 = oc.alt_item_id1 
WHERE 
    owner_id = 'GIII' AND o.alt_item_id1 <> '' 
ORDER BY 
    alt_item_id1, if_updatestamp ASC
```

Not sure how to update the oldest record of every set of duplicate alt_item_id1

I am using SQL Server 2012

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: So you don't in fact have duplicate rows - just duplicate values in alt_item_id1 for the same owner_id, correct? And you want to update im_cust9 for those item_id that have the lowest if_updatestamp of all rows for the same alt_item_id?

Comment: @janschweizer Correct!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update all but one of duplicate records in table in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25090008/update-all-but-one-of-duplicate-records-in-table-in-sql-server)

Comment: In that case I'd recommend replacing your join with a CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ... ORDER BY if_updatestamp DESC) which should list you oldest line for each alt_item_id and go from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the newest row to update, use the max of the **if_updatestamp**. for the oldest use the min. Then join it to your table for the udpate like so...

```
update IM
Set IM.im_cust9 = NewDupeRow.alt_item_id1
From item_master IM
JOIN ( 
SELECT alt_item_id1,Max(if_updatestamp) MaxUpdateValue
 FROM item_master WHERE owner_id='GIII' AND alt_item_id1<>''
 GROUP BY alt_item_id1 ) NewDupeRow
 On IM.alt_item_ID = NewDupeRow.alt_item_ID
 AND IM.if_updatedstamp = NewDupeRow.MaxUpdateValue
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using an updatable CTE and `row_number()`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select i.*,
             row_number() over (partition by alt_item_id order by if_updatestamp) as seqnum
      from item_master i
     )
update toupdate
    set im_cust9 = alt_item_id1
    where seqnum = 1;
```