# Update only one row of duplicate rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a problem. I have tried to search other questions but not working for my problem, so i try to explain it.

I have a table that has 7 columns with 4 primary keys:

Istituto, Filiale, Cdg, Progressivo, DataInserimento, Operatore, Testo

First 4 column are keys and there are sometime record with simil keys (same Istituto, Cdg and Progressivo) but same DataInserimento (that is a DATETIME field), i would found this record and change one (or more if there are more than two record with same date and Cdg) adding 100 ms for distinct date from each other.

For example:

```
Istituto Filiale cdg Progressivo DataInserimento Operatore Testo
1  12 456 1 12/11/2015 12:00:00:200 UGO QUALCOSA
1  123 456 1 12/11/2015 12:00:00:200 UGO QUALCOSA2
1  124 456 1 12/11/2015 12:00:00:200 UGO QUALCOSA3
```

I Would like this after query:

```
Istituto Filiale cdg Progressivo DataInserimento Operatore Testo
1  12 456 1 12/11/2015 12:00:00:200 UGO QUALCOSA
1  123 456 1 12/11/2015 12:00:00:300 UGO QUALCOSA2
1  124 456 1 12/11/2015 12:00:00:400 UGO QUALCOSA3
```

Can I solve this problem?

Comment: You don't have a table with *4 primary keys* - that's impossible, any table can only ever have **ONE** primary key at most. You probably have a primary key, made up from **4 columns** (a compound or composite primary key) - but in your post, you're listing **7** columns ....

Comment: No, same DataInserimento, keys are different for one parameter (in this case for Filiale) but other are the same, i would adding 100 ms for every record with same dataInserimento and same Cdg, Istituto for having record different by DataInserimento

Comment: I have listing all the columns of the table, the first 4 are part of the primary key

Comment: You need to show us some **sample data** and what you want to do to that data (e.g. what you expect as a result from your operation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update all but one of duplicate records in table in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25090008/update-all-but-one-of-duplicate-records-in-table-in-sql-server)

Comment: I edit the post for showing an example, sorry if not explain very good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this UPDATE you change dataInserimento adding a multiple of 100 ms in base of previous rows of your row if exists another row with the same 3 fields of primary key (except Filiale)
Try this:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET dataInserimento = DATEADD(ms, 100 *
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM yourtable T3
    WHERE T3.Istituto = yourtable.Istituto
    AND T3.cdg = yourtable.cdg
    AND T3.Progressivo = yourTable.Progressivo
    AND T3.filiale < yourTable.filiale)
, dataInserimento)
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 'next'
    FROM yourtable t2
    WHERE T2.Istituto = yourtable.Istituto
    AND T2.cdg = yourtable.cdg
    AND T2.Progressivo = yourTable.Progressivo
    AND T2.filiale < yourTable.filiale
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
UPDATE ToUpdate SET DataInserimento = SQ.NewDate
FROM TheTable ToUpdate
JOIN (
    SELECT T.Istituto, T.Cdg, T.Progressivo, T.Filiale, DATEADD(ms, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.Istituto, T.Cdg, T.Progressivo, T.DataInserimento ORDER BY T.Filiale) * 100, T.DataInserimento) AS NewDate
    FROM (
        SELECT Istituto, Cdg, Progressivo, DataInserimento, MIN(Filiale) AS MINFiliale
        FROM TheTable 
        GROUP BY Istituto, Cdg, Progressivo, DataInserimento
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
    ) AS Groups
    JOIN TheTable T ON Groups.Istituto = T.Istituto AND Groups.Cdg = T.Cdg AND Groups.Progressivo = T.Progressivo AND Groups.DataInserimento = T.DataInserimento
    WHERE T.Filiale <> MINFiliale
) SQ ON SQ.Istituto = ToUpdate.Istituto AND SQ.Cdg = ToUpdate.Cdg AND SQ.Progressivo = ToUpdate.Progressivo AND SQ.Filiale = ToUpdate.Filiale
```