# Update all but one duplicate records in table in Snowflake Computing

Tags: sql, duplicates, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using the Snowflake elastic data warehouse provided by Snowflake Computing. I have a table that does not have an identity or primary key column but there are duplicate rows throughout the table.

My problem is that within each duplicated set, I need to update all but one of the duplicated rows from each duplicated set, by zeroing out the `finalsale` and `taxindollars` columns within the table. It doesn't matter which one of the duplicated rows is left untouched/not updated. So, if there are 3 duplicated lines, only 2 of those lines will need to be zeroed out, and the other remaining single line should be untouched. I've tried doing the below query which was given as an answer over here:

[Update all but one of duplicate records in table in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25090008/update-all-but-one-of-duplicate-records-in-table-in-sql-server)

But it doesn't work in Snowflake. It tells me that object 'T' does not exist. The below however returns the exact lines that need to be updated (leaving out 1 line item for each set not to be updated). Any ideas on how I can accomplish this in Snowflake and get all but 1 of the duplicated rows for each duplicated set updated with 0s for `finalsale` and `taxindollars`?

```
UPDATE t SET
    t.finalsale = 0,
    t.taxindollars = 0
FROM (
    SELECT *, row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY 
      saleid,
      locationname,
      customertype,
      finalsale,
      quantity,
      sku                                
    ORDER BY 
        (SELECT NULL)) row_num  
    FROM 
        salesdetail
) t 
WHERE row_num > 1
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just to clarify - are the "duplicates" completely identical records (all attributes), or only duplicates on the attributes you list here? If the former, it might be tricky in Snowflake without some way to identify a particular record.

Comment: Hey @MarcinZukowski, unfortunately it's actually both but I need the update to apply to both situations in the same manner. Right now I'm using a horrible roundabout way to make this work by temporarily creating/using a sequence on the table, and few other steps. A duct tape solution for sure.

Comment: Hey @slybitz. Since Snowflake by itself doesn't have a notion of a "row id" like some databases, it's tricky to update a row found with a SELECT. Using a sequence might be the only way to go if the rows can be "real" duplicates. You could create an auto-generated sequence column, to make it easier. I don't see any other way, but will ask my colleagues to take a look, maybe someone has a good idea.

Comment: Thanks @MarcinZukowski for the feedback here. I've tried a few things around sequencing but nothing super clean. If you come up with anything I'd love to hear about it. Thanks for your help here!

Answer (score 0):

```
--drop table foo purge;
create table foo as 
          select 1 id, 'x' dsc from dual
union all select 1 id, 'x' dsc from dual
union all select 1 id, 'x' dsc from dual
union all select 1 id, 'z' dsc from dual
union all select 1 id, 'z' dsc from dual
union all select 1 id, 'z' dsc from dual
union all select 2 id, 'y' dsc from dual
union all select 2 id, 'y' dsc from dual
union all select 2 id, 'y' dsc from dual;

select * from foo;

create table bar as 
with trg as (select ID
                , DSC
                , row_number() over (partition by ID, DSC order by null) rn
         from foo) 
select ID
       , case when rn = 1 then upper(dsc)
              else dsc
         end DSC
from trg;

truncate table foo;
insert into foo select * from bar;
commit;
drop table bar purge;

select * from foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ROW_NUMBER Partition By Clause and place the Results into a CTE.
It may look something like:

```
 with myData as (
  select mycolumn1, mycolumn2, myDate
    ,row_number() over (partition by mycolumn1 order by myDate desc) as priority
  from source_table
)
select * from myData where priority = 1
```

Then run an select or update on the rows where the number = 1